# MySql перенести таблицу в 800 Гб

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, laravel

Есть сервер, на ходу 24/7,на ней крутиться есть нужная мне таблица таблица в 800 гб.
Ее нужно перенести на новый сервер в связи с разработкой нового ПО.

Никогда такие обьемы не делал на ходу.

Идеи, написать процедуру в базе удаленной которая по лимиту будет потихоньку переносить удаленно данные в новую бд.

Сервер БД сделать mysql dump, архивация и передать на новую.
Но тут может забиться канал сетевой и будут задержки открытия веб сайта.

На ларавель сделать job который будет в течение n времени переносить базу данных.

Как справится что-бы никому не было плохо?

Comment: Перенести надо только одну таблицу? и при этом в принципе без останова сервера?

Comment: Настройка репликации средствами MySQL будет в самый раз

Comment: @Akina именно,без остановки сервера

Comment: @void как поведет себя репликация сразу после настройки? Сразу начнет делать копию себя или только отзеркаливать ново вставленные данные?

Comment: Репликацию без останова не запустить.

Comment: Первым шагом бэкапите только структуру таблицы и создаёте её копию на целевом сервере (само собой. удалив внешние ключи). Далее пишете хранимую процедуру, которая будет по частям делать копию данных таблицы в CSV, либо запускаете внешнюю процедуру, которая так же по частям будет создавать блоки дампов данных. Размер блока придётся подбирать опытным путём - чтобы, с одной стороны, не поставить всех в позу пьющего оленя, съев все ресурсы на эту операцию, и, с другой стороны, не растянуть весь процесс на годы. Типично - это 10-100 тыс. записей. Блоки переносим и заливаем на целевом сервере.

Comment: Вариант с Job вроде бы неплох тоже. Делаешь дамп структуры БД, запихиваешь его в новую базу, и потихоньку перетягиваешь все данные в фоне. Опять же, вопрос в том, насколько это затянется, но я бы делал именно так, если старая база должна постоянно работать

Comment: а еще один вопрос: @АнтонПрохоров вам надо эту одну таблицу один раз перенести или поддерживать её далее в актуальном состоянии на новом сервере? И если поддерживать в актуальном состоянии, то источник обновления данных только "старый сервер" или как?

Answer (score 0):

Выглядит как типичная задача на бинарную репликацию, поднимаете целевой сервер, текущий назначаете мастером, новый слейвом, на мастере ночью запрещаете запись, делаете бекап дампом, разрешаете запись, дамп разворачиваете на новом сервере, включаете репликацию с мастера на слейв, чтобы догнать хвосты, переключаете бекенд на новый сервер, как нагрузка съедет прекращаете репликацию, слейв меняете роль на мастер, старый мастер уничтожаете.
Либо, если вам нужно писать в обе базы - можно попробовать мастер-мастер репликацию, но так будет часто ломаться если нагрузка внятная.
Если дамп предварительно не накатывать а делать репликацию на голую базу - будет очень долго.

Comment: там автор вопроса писал о том, что желательно все сделать без остановки сервера